# Time complexity of hash(str) in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hash

`hash(str)`, how much time does this operation take? 
`O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the string?

(I know hashes are cached.)

To be more specific, does it compute the [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash)

- on call to the `hash(str)`, or
- it compute when you create the string? Since it is immutable, hash should remain the same.

Please provide reference for answer.

Comment: hashes are salted. they do not stay the same over different program runs.

Comment: @PatrickArtner My question is constrained to a single program run.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Wow. That's a bit awful. I couldn't believe it but you are right. Worst thing is it's [not mentioned in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash).

Comment: @PatrickArtner Are you sure that they are salted in this case? These are hashes for dictionary lookups, not for cryptography.

Comment: @StefanFalk Why is that awful? It's to prevent attacks in web servers.

Comment: @StefanFalk The behavior of hash() depends on the object passed to it, meaning it may be salted or not. The documentation for object.__hash__() mentions that the hashes returned are salted for str, bytes, and datetime objects.

Comment: As a sidenote to hash salting, see [this setting](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED)

Comment: @NedBatchelder Well, I don't think that builtin was intended for web servers in particular. If I hear "hash" what I think is that `hash(x) = y` will alway be the same and not `hash(x) = z` the next time I start my server. Anyway, it wouldn't hurt to mention that right in the docs imho ^^

Comment: @StefanFalk a string's hash is used to make key lookups in dicts fast.  When you POST data to a web server, it constructs a dict from the fields.  If string hashes were predictable, a hacker could send a POST with thousands of fields that hashed to the same value, and create an O(n**2) problem on the web server, creating a denial-of-service attack.  You are right that the docs could mention that there is no guarantee that a hash will be consistent between runs.

Comment: The time complexity obviously depends on the implemented algorithm. This may be different for the various Python "flavors". There exists the [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html) library to provide common and secure hash algorithms across all implementations. Of course hash values are only computed when requested, why should they be computed upon instantiation of an object?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=__hash__#cmdoption-r and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?object.__hash__#object.__hash__ for info about hash randomization.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I see. Thanks for that explanation. Always good to learn something new :)

Comment: @a_guest The hashing algorithms in hashlib are cryptographic grade hashes, so they are much slower (and return a lot more bits) than the builtin `hash`, which is simply designed for dict and set use, not data security.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Many (if not most) strings don't go into dicts or sets, so they don't need their hash to be computed, so hashing them on creation would waste both time and RAM.

Comment: And yes, it's O(n), but it's quite fast because it's done at C speed. See https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pyhash.c for details.

Comment: @PM2Ring Sure, I was just saying that the implementation of `hash` may be different for the different implementations of Python while the algorithms in `hashlib` are (of course) the same. Your last comment only applies to CPython which was not specified as part of the question. Python doesn't require a specific implementation for `hash`.

Comment: @a_guest Ah, right. I see what you mean. IMHO, it would be good if the stdlib provided some more non-crypto hash algorithms. `hash` is ok for dicts & sets, but its got pretty poor [avalanching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect).